# Can't initialize array of strings and use them

Tags: c, string, matrix

This is outside the main:

```
char message_ecran[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH+1];
```

And this is my function

```
 int main(void)
    {
        Init(); 

        int i;
        char texte7[] = "io";

        for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
            {
            message_ecran[i] = texte7;
            }
    }
```

I would like to have an array of strings `message_ecran`, but it does'nt work:

```
incompatible types in assignment
```

Comment: You cannot do that in C. Use `strcpy_s` instead of your assignment operator.

Comment: @AnishRam: `strcpy_s` isn't part of the C standard library. Use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: @Zeta, Good point. I didn't know that. Come to think of it, wouldn't `memset` or `memcpy` be better then?

Comment: You should change your for-loop's condition of `i <= NUMBER_OF_STRINGS` into `i < NUMBER...`

Comment: @AnishRam: Well, no. `memcpy` is a general copy algorithm, while `strncpy` will stop on `\0` or if a specified number of characters has been copied (`strncpy` = _str_ ing (_n_ characters) _c_ o _py_)

Comment: That is true. But [this article](http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/strncpy.html) is why I said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy()` , implemented in your program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 3
#define STRING_LENGTH 80

char message_ecran[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH+1];

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char texte7[] = "io";

    for (i=0;i<=NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;i++)
    { 
        strcpy(message_ecran[i],texte7);
        puts(message_ecran[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're doing now is an assignment of the pointer.

You can't simply assign one string to another, you have to `strcpy()` to really copy data.

```
strcpy(message_ecran[i], texte7);
```

Also you have to be sure that there is enough memory allocated in `message_ecran[i]` for string that you're trying to copy. Otherwise, you will corrupt the data.

**EDIT:**

You can check, the following:

```
if(strlen(texte7) < STRING_LENGTH+1)
```

Or you can simply use the following function:

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );

strncpy(message_ecran[i], texte7, STRING_LENGTH);
```

Comment: How should I make sure the memory allocated is sufficient ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use strcpy for copying strings, assignment will not work.
Replace

```
message_ecran[i] = texte7;
```

with

```
strcpy(message_ecran[i], texte7);
```

Answer (score 0):

use strcpy(destination,source) and try